# Json Deserializer retrieves null value in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, observablecollection, json-deserialization, jsonconvert

I have a Xamarin Forms App and all the code seems to be correct, but when I try to serialize the response from the GetAsync request to a Collection the Collection has all of his values null. I already tried with List but same result.

[image]

Observable Collection:

```
        public ObservableCollection<News> NewsCollection
        {
            get { return _newsCollection; }
            set
            {
                _newsCollection = value;
            }
        }
```

Get Request Method:

```
 public async Task<ObservableCollection<News>> GetNews()
        {
                var client = new HttpClient();

                var uri = "http://192.168.1.69:8080/news";
                var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    NewsCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<News>>(content);
                }

                return NewsCollection;
        }
```

My Class:

```
 public class News
    {
        private int id { get; set; }
        private string title { get; set; }
        private string description { get; set; }
        private string link { get; set; }
    }
```

MY JSON:

`"[{\"newId\":11,\"title\":\"Coins Lose All Intrest, Bitcoin Rules \",\"description\":\"Lorem ipsu mipsm lorum O estado adota a moeda digital Bitcoin como moeda oficial do pais. Grande alta nos mercados crypto depois desta noticia ter explodido bla bl bla bla \",\"link\":\"www.fakeNews.com\"},{\"newId\":12,\"title\":\"Coins Lose All Intrest, Bitcoin Rules \",\"description\":\"Lorem ipsu mipsm lorum O estado adota a moeda digital Bitcoin como moeda oficial do pais. Grande alta nos mercados crypto depois desta noticia ter explodido bla bl bla bla \",\"link\":\"www.fakeNews.com\"},{\"newId\":13,\"title\":\"Coins Lose All Intrest, Bitcoin Rules \",\"description\":\"Lorem ipsu mipsm lorum O estado adota a moeda digital Bitcoin como moeda oficial do pais. Grande alta nos mercados crypto depois desta noticia ter explodido bla bl bla bla \",\"link\":\"www.fakeNews.com\"},{\"newId\":14,\"title\":\"Coins Lose All Intrest, Bitcoin Rules \",\"description\":\"Lorem ipsu mipsm lorum O estado adota a moeda digital Bitcoin como moeda oficial do pais. Grande alta nos mercados crypto depois desta noticia ter explodido bla bl bla bla \",\"link\":\"www.fakeNews.com\"},{\"newId\":16,\"title\":\"Coins Lose All Intrest, Bitcoin Rules \",\"description\":\"Lorem ipsu mipsm lorum O estado adota a moeda digital Bitcoin como moeda oficial do pais. Grande alta nos mercados crypto depois desta noticia ter explodido bla bl bla bla \",\"link\":\"www.fakeNews.com\"},{\"newId\":17,\"title\":\"Coins Lose All Intrest, Bitcoin Rules \",\"description\":\"Lorem ipsu mipsm lorum O estado adota a moeda digital Bitcoin como moeda oficial do pais. Grande alta nos mercados crypto depois desta noticia ter explodido bla bl bla bla \",\"link\":\"www.fakeNews.com\"},{\"newId\":18,\"title\":\"Coins Lose All Intrest, Bitcoin Rules \",\"description\":\"Lorem ipsu mipsm lorum O estado adota a moeda digital Bitcoin como moeda oficial do pais. Grande alta nos mercados crypto depois desta noticia ter explodido bla bl bla bla \",\"link\":\"www.fakeNews.com\"}]"`

Comment: Please, add your JSON too

Comment: And verify your news class, all props are PRIVATE

Comment: [Serialization Guide / Objects](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#Objects): *"By default ... all **public** fields and properties with getters are automatically serialized to JSON ..."*

Comment: Already Working thanks a lot u are the best Mate, the props of the class must be public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify your class, your need public methods to serialize.

```
public class News
{
    private int id { get; set; }
    private string title { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Try

```
public class News
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#Objects